# Unable to open RStudio exported files by Illustrator

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2, rstudio

I was plotting a stacked line image on RStudio, with a list like:

- Date A   B   C   D
- 1002EST  0.225164194 0.089942967 0.684289684 0.000603155
- 1007EST  0.606697971 0.375931286 0.015410986 0.001959757
- 1012EST  0.745430542 0.240069576 0.01186502  0.002634862
- 1017EST  0.586552052 0.253384789 0.159091468 0.000971692
- 1022EST  0.719846808 0.085252303 0.193054704 0.001846186
- 1106EST  0.908801738 0.075007121 0.015196251 0.00099489
- 1111EST  0.901317416 0.083624883 0.011020257 0.004037444
- 1116EST  0.838439325 0.116000974 0.042570946 0.002988756
- 1121EST  0.822848944 0.14935052  0.024948372 0.002852164
- 1126EST  0.878149037 0.107215826 0.011199368 0.003435768
- 1206EST  0.806550999 0.127171158 0.062039302 0.00423854
  The code is like:

  ```
  {library(reshape2)
  Data_Melt <- melt(Test, "Date")
  library(ggplot2)
  p<-ggplot(Data_Melt, aes(Date, value)) + geom_area(aes(fill = variable,group = variable))
  p<-p+theme_light()
  p<-p+theme(axis.text.x= element_text(size=10,color="black",family="Arial",angle=60,vjust=1,hjust=1),axis.text.y=element_text(size=10,family="Arial"))
  p<-p+scale_x_discrete(limits = Test$Date)}
  ```

I used the export option on preview window in RStudio and generate both svg and pdf files, which looked like:
[image: Plot]

However, when I tried to open the files in Adobe Illustrator for editing, I found both encounter difficulties.
With svg file, the Illustrator shows a stack of letters:
[image: Screeshot1]

With pdf file, it could not show the letters:
[image: Screenshot2]

I thought it should be some font problems, but could not figure out why. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried .eps-files: `setEPS(); postscript(...)`?

Comment: Try http://community.rstudio.com/ for RStudio weirdness. Its not a programming problem.